# Updating integer field in a row by 1 using php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I want to find the row where the username, password, email country etc. matches and update "points" in that row by 1 point. Why isn't my code working?

```php
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("mysql_host","mysql_user","mysql_password","mysql_database");

$country = $_POST["country"];
$district = $_POST["district"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];



$query = "UPDATE table SET points=points+1 WHERE country = ? AND district = ? username = ? AND email = ? AND password = ?";
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isssss", $points, $country, $district, $username, $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Remove the `i` binding. You do not need `$points`.

Comment: There's a missing AND between district and username in the where clause.

Comment: Yeah, your right about the i. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET points=points+1 WHERE country = ? AND district = ? username = ? AND email = ? AND password = ?";
```

to

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET points=points+1 WHERE country = ? AND district = ? AND username = ? AND email = ? AND password = ?";
```

Comment: I changed that now, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for finding the typo anyways :)

Comment: I've added the extra AND now but it still doesn't work. Other ideas? Thanks for finding the "AND" typo anyways :)